# Writing Classes what am I missing?

Tags: java

I have a project that Ive made so far and here are my desired outputs:

**Test 1**

[image]

and

**Test 2**

[image]

Here are the directions."Write a class called Book that contains instance data for the title, author, and pages. Define the Book constructor to accept and initialize this data. Include setter and getter methods for all instance data. Include a toString methods that returns a string like below:

> ```
> Author: name of the author in one word
>
> Title: title in one word
>
> Pages: number of pages
> ```

example:

> ```
> Author: Lewis
>
> Title: Java
>
> Pages: 806
> ```

Write a BookTester class to take author, title, pages from keyboard, create a book object and print the above to the screen. How would I get my answer to show the expected outputs shown in my pictures Test1 and Test 2? Also, what am I missing?

Book

```
    public class Book {
        String author;
        String title;
        int pages;

        public Book(String a, String t, int p) {
        author = a;
        title = t;
        pages = p;
    }

        public String toString() {
        String output;
        output = ("Author: " + author + "\n");
        output = ("Title: " + title + "\n");
        output = ("Pages: " + pages + "\n");
        return output;
    }
}
```

BookTester

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class BookTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String author;
    String title;
    int pages;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    author = scan.nextLine();
    title = scan.nextLine();
    pages = scan.nextInt();
    Book book1 = new Book(author, title, pages);
    System.out.println(book1);
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    String output ="";
    output += "Author: " + author + "\n";
    output += "Title: " + title + "\n";
    output += "Pages: " + pages + "\n";
    return output;
}
```

You should concat (+) each value. Otherwise last value (means `Pages: ---`) will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public String toString() {
    String output = "Author: " + author + "\n" + "Title: " + title + "\n" + "Pages: " + pages + "\n";
    return output;
}
```

You were constantly replacing the returned `Output` string rather than adding on to it.

Comment: `return String output` is not valid. Please correct your answer.

Comment: @grzesiekw My bad. Not sure how that got there!

Answer (score 0):

The programm is not working because you are rewriting the output in the **toString** method:

```
public String toString() {
    String output;
    output = ("Author: " + author + "\n");
    output = ("Title: " + title + "\n");
    output = ("Pages: " + pages + "\n");
    return output;
}
```

---

a couple of thing must be done to fix this.

```
@override
public String toString() {
    String output;
    output += "Author: " + author + "\n";
    output += "Title: " + title + "\n";
    output += "Pages: " + pages + "\n";
    return output;
}
```

dont forget the **@override**, this is a good practice,

**Final recomendation**:
It is always a good idea to make use of your IDE's features to generate the toString method. Don't hand-code it.

For instance, I see you are using Eclipse, this IDE can do so if you simply right-click on the source code and select Source > Generate toString